# External language file

Tags: php

I have a little bit confusing problem.

I have website with multiple languages. For default labels and headings I made some external php file where I have variables with values for different languages.

For example, In file I have variable

**$heading = "First Heading in English"**

and variable

**$heading = "First Heading in German"**...

In session I have stored value for current language, and with if state I know what language variables to take.

My problem is next:

When I load my page for first time, all of fields where I call variables from external language file are empty...

And, when I refresh my page, variables are there, with right value....

Can someone help me with this problem??

I include external file before everything in my php file, with **include** function.

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Session is created when user choose language, probably? And default one is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you include the file?

Perhaps first language variable is not saved in session yet.

It is always a good idea to check if language is not set you are going to use some default value i.e english.

```
if (!isset($language)) {
    $language = 'en';
}
```

Comment: That was a problem :) ... Session didn't saved variable :) Thanks a lot, bro! :)

Answer (score 0):

Modified this a little bit from what i have written a while ago...maybe this will help you a little bit.

```
$langSession = $_SESSION['lang'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['lang']){ // if the Session with language was not set

$browserlang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2); // Get the browser setting language, tested it in firefox

   if($browserlang == "de"){
       $_SESSION['lang'] = "de"; // German

   }elseif($browserlang == "nl"){ // Dutch
      $_SESSION['lang'] = "nl";
   }else{ // Else English
      $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
   }
}
include('language.php');
```